# AWS EKS Workshop displays access denied for many sections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

Asking here out of desperation as I already tried to post to AWS forums but it consistently fails with 500 error for every topic I'm trying to post.

Going step by step on this tutorial: https://eksworkshop.com/

I've finished this step:
https://eksworkshop.com/prerequisites/sshkey/

And now I'm clicking on next arrow which opens this:
https://eksworkshop.com/eksctl/

But the browser yells

```xml
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>AF5B4DEC2EE61B39</RequestId>
<HostId>
i+dwVcZNMgqqd+K/NzR0oVGW1uPZ3FzepnhIzofJK1vDceE91/gYb6NV1D0BQRtgbWIIKD41cjE=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I noticed it happens for many other sections.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this is yelling about the access denied, but, you can use this link which is the same as [eksctl workshop](http://eksworkshop.com/030_eksctl).

Or, you can just read the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html) which is the same as the workshop.

Comment: Thanks Amit. Apparently they changed navigation menu structure and my browser had old cached version or something. I had to disable cache in Network tab in chrome debug tools and reload eksworkshop.com and now I see the changed structure and your link is there too.

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)